# How should my usercontrol notify my view?

Tags: c#, wpf, model-view-controller, mvvm, user-controls

IN WPF I am trying to be as MVC/VM as possible. I have a user control (ReservationDataControl) that has a datagrid with a context menu and some filter buttons. The user can add, delete, etc from the context menu and it's all handled within the usercontrol. This control is on the same window as another usercontrol where I gather statistics about how many people paid and how much was earned (PartyStatsControl).

When the user edits the ReservationDataControl I need the PartyStatsControl to update (so they will be valid). What is the best MVC/VM way to do that?

Should I just raise an event from ReservationDataControl? Is there a way of binding a command? What is the accepted way for a control to notify it's host of changes in MVC/VM.

BTW: I use MVC/VM because I've never managed to get the differences between the two straight in my head and rather than argue about with methodology I'm using I'll just cop to not knowing right off the bat.

Comment: It's just what the event aggregator was made for.  You can also use rx to expose a service, depending upon your design.

Comment: What is the difference between an event and an EventAggregator for a single event?

Comment: One is decoupled, the other is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most thing engineering, there's not **right** and **wrong** answer, and it all depends on the scenario. Handling the event in code behind and calling your view model appropriately is perfectly fine (providing you've passed a reference of the view model into your view upon instantiating).

You can, however bind to commands, and I do prefer this method as it more loosely coupled. The actions in this command will set your **model** (in this case, the **_statistics** instance passed in upon creation of your **ReservationDataViewModel**).

ReservationDataControl View:

```
<Button Command={Binding ClickCommand}/>
```

ReservationDataControl View Model (Data Context):

```
private readonly Statistics _statistics;

public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }

private ReservationDataViewModel(Statistics statistics)
{
    _statistics = statistics;

    InitialiseCommands();
}

private void InitialiseCommands()
{
    ClickCommand = new RoutedUICommand("ClickCommand", "ClickCommand", typeof(ViewModel));
    CommandBinding clickCommandBinding = new CommandBinding(ClickCommand, ExecuteClickCommand, ClickCommandCanExecute);
    CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(ViewModel), clickCommandBinding);
}

private void ExecuteClickCommand(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    // perform click logic here...

    // e.g. say there is a property on your statistics called 'ReservationCount'
    // the command adds a reservation (increments the count)
    _statistics.ReservationCount += 1;
}

private void ClickCommandCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs args)
{
    args.CanExecute = true; // put your can execute logic here...
}
```

Now, if your model (i.e. **Statistics** class) is set up correctly, it should have a way of telling any code who cares that it has changed.

i.e.

```
public class Statistics
{
    public event EventHandler ReservationCountChanged;

    private int _reservationCount;

    // think about how you may restrict set access for this model
    public int ReservationCount 
    { 
        get { return _reservationCount; } 
        protected set
        {
            if (_reservationCount != value)
            {
                _reservationCount = value;

                if (ReservationCountChanged != null)
                    ReservationCountChanged(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }

    public Statistics() { }
}
```

Now, your **PartyStatsViewModel** can pick up on this change, originated from the **ReservationDataViewModel** and update it's view with standard WPF binding implementation.

PartyStatsControl View Model:

```
private readonly Statistics _statistics;

public int ReservationCount
{
    get { return _statistics.ReservationCount; }
    set
    {
        _statistics.ReservationCount = value;

        OnPropertyChanged("ReservationCount");
    }
}               

public PartyStatsControlViewModel(Statistics statistics)
{
    _statistics = statistics;

    _statistics.ReservationCountChanged += OnReservationCountChanged;
}

private void OnReservationCountChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
    // todo: force this onto the UI thread or exceptions will occur
    this.ReservationCount = ((Statistics)sender).ReservationCount;
}
```

Comment: So it would be more appropriate to have a Dependency Property on my UserControl that calls a RoutedCommand after finishing it's own processing? Then the view can respond to that Command by calling the Refresh on the second control?

Comment: Ok it sounds like I may have misunderstood the initial requirement. You have a usercontrol that will alter some data, and you want some second control to automatically reflect the state of this data?

Comment: Yep! That's the gist.

Comment: There. I've made some edits to the original question that may more accurately reflect my situation.

Comment: It sounds like you have a common model - your statistics - that one control can edit and another control can display (or edit, it doesn't really matter). The point is, it shouldn't be the responsibility of one control to know when to update another control and vice versa. Each control should be responsible for itself. The common part here is, of course, your model. So keep it simple - one control makes a change on the model, and the other control simply observes for any changes and updates itself accordingly. See edited answer for example.

Comment: I think I get it. Bind the StatsControl directly to the ReservationControl. The MainView should have no reason to intervene. That makes sense, thanks.